# How can a low-power microcontroller authenticate itself against a server?

Tags: authentication, encryption, microcontroller

Currently I am working on an embedded project. The client side is an 8bits MCU and the server side is computer.

As part of goal, I want to minimize the chance people copy our product. During the initialization phase, the server send its serial number to client and client do some simple calculation with its serial number then send result back to server. The server checks the result to a pre-calculated, hardcoded value, if match the client is authentic.

The problem is the calculated serial number that sent back to server is always fixed. Any copycat company can figure it out quite easily with a logic analyzer. I want to make the transmitting serial number seems random bits from time to time but still be able to decrypt back to its original value. [A good example using AES encryption](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/aes.html) (notice every time you press the *Encrypt It* button a seemingly random text is generated, but as you decrypt it, then it reverts to the original text.)

Due to ROM/RAM and process power limitation in 8bits MCU I can’t fit a complete AES routine in it, so AES is out of a solution. Is there an easy and efficiency algorithm just to randomize the transmission?

Comment: Client(8bits MCU) side is coding in C with math library & true random number generator (TRNG) available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a key pair.  On initialization:

- Client tells server "I am online"
- Server encrypts a verification message, which only the client will be able to decode
- Client sends back the decrypted message

There should be no need for the server's key to be hardcoded - it can be generated based on a timestamp (only an answer within an acceptable range is accepted) or the codes can be generated on an as-needed basis with a timeout to prevent them from being stored for a long term.

Answer (score 0):

Have the server send either a monotonically-increasing counter or a timestamp to the client, alongside the serial number.  The client then includes that in the calculation it performs.

Because the server always sends a different request, the response will always be different (of course, if the market is lucrative enough your competitors can always disassemble your MCU code and figure out how to replicate it, but there's really no stopping that).

Answer (score 0):

A different idea might be to require the 8 bit controller to send a CRC of the date, time and serial number to the server. The server can verify it is a unique serial and send a CRC with date, time and authorization code.

You might also look into the rolling code algorythms used for garage doors openers to see if they could be applied to your application.